# Import in postgres json data in a csv file

Tags: postgresql, import, json, csv

I'm trying to import into postgres a `csv` file containing the data for a table. One of the column of the table has `jsonb` type.

One line of my `csv` file contains something like

```
1,{"a":"b"}
```

Suppose the table has a schema

```
id              | smallint          | 
data            | jsonb             |
```

If I try just to insert the data, everything works fine

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, '{"a":"b"}');
```

Trying to import directly from the file with

```
COPY table FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' csv;
```

gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "a" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {a...
COPY availability, line 1, column services: "{a: b}"
```

I tried to quote the fields with `'`, with `"`, with `\"` and `\'`, but nothing works..

Which is the correct syntax do do it?

Comment: Can you check out my answer. =)

Answer (score 8):

The PostgreSQL `COPY` command is seldom ideal, but it often works. For reference there are better methods to figure this out than guessing.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE baz AS
  SELECT 1::int, '{"a":"b"}'::jsonb;
```

This is your exact sample data. Now we can test different settings..

```
# COPY baz TO STDOUT;
1   {"a": "b"}

COPY baz TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',';
1,{"a": "b"}
```

You'll see that the above generates the exact data your questioning...

```
COPY baz TO '/tmp/data.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

There is no problem. At least not with PostgreSQL 9.5.

## CSV Mode

So where is your problem, it's with CSV-mode. Observe,

```
# COPY baz TO STDOUT;
1   {"a": "b"}
# COPY baz TO STDOUT CSV;
1,"{""a"": ""b""}"
```

You can see these two are different now. Let's try to load the non-CSV file in CSV mode which assumes the format that CSV mode generated above.

```
TRUNCATE baz;
COPY baz FROM '/tmp/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "a" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {a...
COPY baz, line 1, column jsonb: "{a: b}"
```

Now we error. The reason for that comes from [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)

> Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>          some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>          at all).  **If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>          double quotes may not appear inside the fields.**

1. So [JSON RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifies an object's *names* in name/value pairs must be strings which require double quotes.
2. And [CSV RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) specifies that if any double quotes are inside the field, then the whole field must be quoted.

At this point you have two options..

1. Don't use CSV mode.
2. Or, Escape the inner quotes.

So these would be valid inputs under the same options in CSV mode.

```
#COPY baz TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV ESCAPE E'\\';
1,"{\"a\": \"b\"}"

# COPY baz TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV;
1,"{""a"": ""b""}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, postgres uses `"` as an escaping character, so the correct format should be

```
{"""a""": """b"""}
```

Comment: You can specify the escape character for the `copy` command with the `escape` option

Comment: I don't think this is true. Yes, `"` is an escaping character, so you need `"{""a"": ""b""}"` not triple quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers the *CSV* and the *JSON* specs (and probably the *postgresql* specs) are somewhat incompatible.  To get them to stop fighting, at least in their simple forms, you have to escape things until they're an unreadable mess.  Not using *CSV* mode is even worse as the **COPY** will die on anything that *JSON* has an issue with: embedded new lines, back-slashes or quote marks.

I had your exact same problem only with a much more complex input: a bunch of **ENUM** types, integers and complex *JSON* fields.  To wit:

```
create table messages( a blab, b integer, c text, d json, e json);
```

where the typical *JSON*s would be `{"default":"little","sms":"bigger"}` and `["name","number"]`.  Try importing a pile of those with a **COPY** command: if the commas inside the *JSON* don't get you the quote marks will!  I spend hours on this until i found [this fine blog post](http://adpgtech.blogspot.ca/2014/09/importing-json-data.html) which pointed out the causes of the problem and the options you need to get out of it.

Basically you need to change the delimiter and quote fields to something that you can guarantee won't be in your *JSON* data.  In my case I can guarantee a lot so I can just go

```
COPY messages( a, b, c, d, e) from stdin  csv quote '^' delimiter '|';
malfunction|5|La la la|{"default":"little","sms":"bigger"}|["name","number"]
```

Nice and readable, easy to get to with some minor character substitution in your favourite text mangler, and no escaping of no nothing!  If you can't guarantee that the characters used above can't be in your *JSON* then you can use the rather wacky `e'\x01'` and `e'\x02'` as the *JSON* spec deems them totally illegal.  Not quite as readable and so forth but punctiliously correct.

Note that embedded new-lines, as some *JSON* generators tend to emit for readability purposes, are still 'no-no's so you have to filter them out of your *JSON*.

Comment: This is the best answer. I used the "rather wacky" option and it worked well. Note: provide col names if tables have different order of col names. Escape col names with upper case. 

`psql "host=host1 user=django_api_sync dbname=database2 password=..." -c "COPY table1 TO stdout (FORMAT csv, HEADER 1, quote e'\x01', delimiter e'\x02') " | tee data.csv | psql "host=localhost user=dbuser dbname=database1 password=..." -c "COPY table1 (\"Col1_ID\",col2, col3) from stdin (FORMAT csv, HEADER 1, quote e'\x01', delimiter e'\x02')"
`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql) do to the job and it worked fine. spyql can generate `INSERT` statements that you can use to import the data into your db. spyql is based on python and the standard csv lib would not work well if your jsons have several keys, since the delimiter is the same. Therefore, the approach I suggest is manually splitting each line into two columns:

```
$ spyql -Otable=table_name "SELECT col1.split(',',1)[0] AS id, col1.split(',', 1)[1] AS data FROM text TO sql" < sample.csv 
INSERT INTO "table_name"("id","data") VALUES ('1','{"a":"b"}'),('2','{"a":"foo", "b": 2}');
```

This assumes only 2 columns as in the example, and no header row.

Importing the data into postgres could be done by piping the output into psql:

```
$ spyql -Otable=table_name "SELECT col1.split(',',1)[0] AS id, col1.split(',', 1)[1] AS data FROM text TO sql" < sample.csv | psql -h my_host -U my_user my_db
```

You would have to create the table in the database beforehand, but that's it.

Disclosure: I am the author of spyql

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to put double quotes around the entire JSON object and change each double quote within the object to two double quotes. So basically this

```
{ "a": 1, "b": "two" }
```

became this:

```
"{ ""a"": 1, ""b"": ""two"" }"
```